# react-native navigator replace with same scene

Tags: react-native

I am currently working on a react-native project with a navigator in the app.
The behavior i am looking for can be explained by the below scene navigations:

```
a->b->c->c
```

Note the transition from c to c.

Assuming i am in component

```
class ComponentC extends Component
{
    // Some code
}
```

Inside this `// Some code` I want to use the

`this.props.navigator.replace({ component:"ComponentC" });`

which is available in any scene of this navigator, but i can't make it reload the current scene, or replace the current scene with itself.

I hope i was able to deliver my issue clearly, i am available for any feedback.

Thank you all

Comment: What do you mean by _i can't make it reload the current scene, or replace the current scene with itself_ ? Is there an error ?